# How to connect two resources that have a N to N relationship

Tags: terraform

I am developing a module that creates:

- Applications
- Set of environment variables
- Environment variables

Some important information:

- Each application belongs to one or more environments (e.g., dev, stage, prod)
- Each application can have zero or more sets of environments variables
- All environment variables belong to one set of environment variables

Here's the code:

```
locals {
  apps = {
    "app01" = { envs = ["dev", "prod"] },
    "app02" = { envs = ["dev"] }
  }
  flatten_apps = flatten([
    for app_key, app_value in local.apps : [
      for env in app_value.environments : [
        { "${app_key}-${env}" = merge(app_value, { environment = "${env}" }) }
      ]
    ]
  ])
  # Result of the variable apps_envs below:
  # apps_envs = {
  #   "app01-dev"  = { envs = ["dev", "prod"], environment = "dev" },
  #   "app01-prod" = { envs = ["dev", "prod"], environment = "prod" },
  #   "app02-dev"  = { envs = ["dev"], environment = "dev" },
  # }
  apps_envs = { for app in local.flatten_apps : keys(app)[0] => values(app)[0] }
  env_vars = {
    "dev" = {
      "var01" = { value = "value01" }
      "var02" = { value = "value02" }
    }
    "prod" = {
      "var03" = { value = "value03" }
    }
  }
  # Result of the flattening below:
  # flatten_env_vars = [
  #   {
  #     environment = "dev"
  #     key         = "var01"
  #     value       = "value01"
  #   },
  #   {
  #     environment = "dev"
  #     key         = "var02"
  #     value       = "value02"
  #   },
  #   {
  #     environment = "prod"
  #     key         = "var03"
  #     value       = "value03"
  #   },
  # ]
  flatten_env_vars = flatten([
    for env_name, env_env_vars in local.env_vars : [
      for env_var_key, env_var_value in env_env_vars : [
        merge(env_var_value, { environment = env_name, key = env_var_key })
      ]
    ]
  ])
}

# The resource below creates all applications (e.g., app01-dev, app01-prod, app02-dev)
resource "application" "apps" {
  for_each = local.apps_envs
  name     = each.key
}

# The resource below creates a set of environment variables
resource "set_of_env_vars" "env_vars" {
  for_each = local.env_vars
  name     = "${each.key}-env-vars"
}

# The resource below creates an env. variable and attaches it to a set
resource "env_var" "env_vars" {
  count = length(local.flatten_env_vars)

  key   = local.flatten_env_vars[count.index].key
  value = local.flatten_env_vars[count.index].value

  set_of_env_vars_id = resource.set_of_env_vars[local.flatten_env_vars[count.index].environment].id
}

# The resource below attaches each set to an application
resource "application_set_of_env_vars" "app_set" {
  # ?
}
```

I can't figure out how to attach each set to the correct application using `application_set_of_env_vars` resource. Each set and application belong to an environment, and now I need to connect them.

There's no `environment` resource, and I can't create it. I am implementing something that the provider doesn't have.

It would be solved with nested loops, but I don't know how to do it in Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "application_set_of_env_vars" "app_set" {
for_each = local.flatten_env_vars

application_id = lookup(local.apps_envs, "${each.environment}-${each.key}").id
set_of_env_vars_id = lookup(local.env_vars, "${each.environment}").id
}
```

This will create an `application_set_of_env_vars` resource for each environment variable in `local.flatten_env_vars`, and will attach the environment variables to the corresponding application based on the environment name.